# Hosting blazor wasm asp.net core hosted app in kestrel

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, kestrel-http-server

I am having troubles hosting the `blazor wasm asp.net core hosted` application.. The solution has 3 projects: **Client**, **Shared**, and **Server**.

when I run the command `dotnet publish --configuration Release` it publishes the libraries to their respective folders in solution like this:

- WebWorkbench3\**Client**\bin\Release\net5.0\publish
- WebWorkbench3\**Server**\bin\Release\net5.0\publish
- ...

I would assume that since the `server` project is referencing a `client` - then my steps to host the application are following:

1. Open `WebWorkbench3\Server\bin\Release\net5.0\publish` in powershell
2. Run command `dotnet .\WebWorkbench3.Server.dll`

[image]

3. Navigate to: `https://localhost:5001/`
4. Result:

- **Expected:** client page opened
- **Actual:** page is stuck at "Loading.." string. In the console we see that there was an error about `_framework/blazor.webassembly.js` not being loaded.

[image]

5. If we were to check the `wwwroot` folder contents in the server app we will see the following:

[image]

So this explains why the error is shown. However my question at this point - should the publishing process/configuration in project take care of **copying** client's `wwwroot` contents into the the server's app output directory? If we start a debugging session in the VisualStudio, then we use the `server` as the startup point, so the project should have some idea where to look up the `blazor.webassembly.js` file at..

[image]

So why doesn't the same process occurs during the publishing?

**Note:** I was able to fix the issue by manually copying the client's `wwwroot` directory and by placing the contents into the server's `wwwroot` directory... But I don't think that is is how serving is supposed to work?

**EDIT:** I have just tried to set-up the `client` blazor application in IIS. And it works. Kind of. The page is opened. But then when it tries to make a REST GET request to the server - it uses the same `hostname:port` combination. So if my app is hosted on `mysite.local:50001` then the request to API will look like `mysite.local:50001/data/loadall` where `data` is the controller name and `loadall` is the action name.. So basically the client uses the same base address as the server.. The problem, is that I cannot start the server on the same port as the client! In attempt in doing so - you will see following output:
[image]

So basically I have the same question as before - how to host the wasm application that is split between client and the server? I am pretty sure that I can make it work by forcing the client to use the non-standard server port and serving the `server` part on that port.. However, I believe there should be a reason why current configuration (default configuration in the blazor wasm template) is configured in this way so it should be possible to run the project somehow without any additional changes at all..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this will be a self-answer.. Instead of publishing (`dotnet publish --configuration Release`) the application on solution level - do the publishing on project level..

- before `..\repos\WebWorkbench3\WebWorkbench3`
- after `..\repos\WebWorkbench3\WebWorkbench3\Server`

In 1 case the compiler does not copy the `_framework` folder (and possibly some other files) into the `wwwroot`.. Once you have published the Server correctly you can access the app by serving it with `dotnet .\WebWorkbench3.Server.dll` command.

Comment: Thanks for this post and self-answer! It really helped me out. I couldn't figure out why my Blazor client's wwwroot/_framework directory wasn't being published, but I was using a solution publish. Doing an individual project publish fixed that. Very subtle.

Comment: Great question and answer, mine not working yet but I'm shocked that there is thousands of tutorials of how to make an wasm core website but zero tutorials of how to publish it in a real scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Having the samie issue as explained above:

**Before:**
The solution file

- had the same name
- was in the same folder

as the server project

**Resolved**
I moved the solution to the project root (one level up).

Now, `dotnet publish` within the server project produced the `__framework` folder + content as expected.